# Condition inside function call in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to implement a geometric multiplication using SQL in Sybase. I have percentages ranging from -100 to +infinity. As there is no product aggregation in Sybase, I am using the approximation with the exp and log methods. Log is not defined for log(0), so I have to catch the value -100.

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
SELECT KEY, IF VALUE <= EXP(SUM(LOG(CASE WHEN VALUE <= -100 THEN 0 ELSE 1+VALUE / 100 END)))
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY KEY
```

the query part `CASE WHEN VALUE <= -100 THEN 0 ELSE 1+VALUE / 100 END` is valid outside a function, but not inside the log function it appears.

Error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword `FROM`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You say log(0) is not defined, and then try to compute it when `VALUE <= -100`. Is this intentional?

Comment: fwiw: looks like you're selecting two values - KEY followed by a garbled/incomplete "if" statement.  I don't have access to a Sybase server (is it IQ or ASE you use btw?) to test, but if CASE doesn't work inside LOG() then invert the logic and put separate LOG()s inside two branches of a CASE.

Comment: If you're trying to have a `VALUE <= -100` not contribute to the summation, you should make the `CASE` statement return 1, because `log(1)=0`

Comment: If you're going to edit the example code in the question, consider adding it to the end of the question instead of changing the initial code. Now the note directly below the code does not make sense.

Comment: Yeah I started correcting the line and I thought about the same think so I wrote it back the wrong way for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have taken a coffee before this one... Thanks for the help.

1. `IF VALUE <=` should not be there at all. This is coming from an old test I did and forgot to remove it.
2. `LOG()` is at the wrong place.

Here is the correct answer:

```
SELECT KEY, EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE <= -100 THEN 0 ELSE LOG(1+VALUE / 100) END))
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY KEY
```

EDIT: Actually, since the value was in percent, it might be more logic to get the end result also in percent:

```
SELECT KEY, (EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE <= -100 THEN 0 ELSE LOG(1+VALUE / 100) END)) - 1) * 100
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY KEY
```

Comment: That makes more sense! I was wondering how getting booleans was going to help, but assumed that the question was for a precursor to the function itself.